# Expose Interface from a WAR file

Tags: java, plugins, interface

I want to write a plugin for my web application.

I have an interface which is in the WAR file. Now in the plugin which will be a JAR file, I want to use this interface.

How can I do it? I don't want the coding part, what I am looking for is the approach to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the interface out of the WAR file and into a JAR file. Make the WAR file depend on the JAR file, and make your plugin JAR file depend on it as well.

You cannot have a JAR file depend on a WAR file directly.

Comment: I had thought of this . . but can I do it without moving out the interface ? Can ServiceLoader be of any help here ? I could not understand what for is ServiceLoader exactly used . .

Comment: I am going to do by this approach only . .